# What is the simplest solution to flat an javascript array of objects into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, destructuring

Is there any way to convert below array:

```
[
  {x: 1},
  {y: 2}
]
```

to this object:

```
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
```

using destructuring in javascript?

I tried different patterns with no luck.

Comment: Hello, I am also new with Js and this is my solution:
`a.forEach((obj)=>{Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{b[key]=obj[key]})})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as follows:

```js
const array = [
  {x: 1},
  {y: 2}
]

const object = array.reduce((target, item) => {
  
  // Use spread to merge current array item object 
  // into target object
  return { ...target, ...item }
}, {})

console.log(object);
```

The idea here is to iterate each item of your input `array` via the reduction and, for each iteration, merge the current array `item` into the `target` object (which will be the resulting `object` of the operation).

Note the order that `target` and `item` are spread into the result of the reduction; if any keys conflict during the merge of `item` and `target`, the values from `item` will be used.